# Update a file if it is common for two directory and delete it when its uniquely in one directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Suppose Directory1 has

```
1.File1 
2.File2
3.Subdirectory1
    Subdirectory1 has :
    3.1. File 3
    3.2. File 4
```

and

Directory2 has

```
1.File1
2.File3
3.Subdirectory1
    Subdirectory1 has :
    3.1. File 3
    3.2. File 6
```

If any file is uniquely present in Directory2 it has to be deleted.
If the file is present in both Directory1 and Directory2 , files in Directory1 has to be copied to Directory2 with the same folder structure [Updates].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given two directory trees, how can I find out which files differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4997693/608639), [Difference between two directories in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16787916/608639), [Shell script to compare directories recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765054/608639), [Compare two folders which has many files inside contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644593/608639), [How to compare files with same names in two different directories using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119788/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use diff, eg :

```
diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1
Only in dir1: file2
Only in dir1/subdir1: file4
Only in dir2/subdir1: file6
```

You can then awk, or store the result in a temporary file and use it in your script.

Comment: Thanks . I initially started with this approach . Faced problems when the files had same name in sub-directories .

Comment: In this case you can use "find /dir1/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > dir1.txt" then same on dir2 than diff. Another solution is to use git !

Comment: So it is impossible to create same hashmap for two non identical files , But the files in Directory1 will always be an update over files in directory2 [GIVEN] . In these conditions files in directory2 has to be replaced by files from directory1 .

Comment: That's why i think you should combine the different approaches in a script. md5sum will just tell you that files are really different even if same name. If the important thing for you is not the name but the content, you script should always copy / move the file from dir1 to dir2 in any case...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to talk about a mirroring function, see the nice Open Source tool rsync.
https://rsync.samba.org/

It can do all of that and even more (also remote synchronization via LAN or via SSH if needed).

```
rsync -options --otherOptions sourceDir targetDir
```

Usually you would use these commandline options:

```
rsync -av /src/foo /dest
or
rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
```

Note: if you omit the trailing "/" of /src/foo, then rsync will mirror to /dest and create a foo subdir. You have either the one or the other choice how to use this command.